# Asus P5Q w/ 16 GB of RAM?

Tags: memory, motherboard

I just bought 4x 4GB RAM sticks (A-TECH, bottom in pic) to try to upgrade my machine to 16GB which is the max per ASUS specs for this motherboard, but I've tried installing each one and I can't even get the machine to POST. No beeps, no feedback of any kind, simply black screen when I turn it on.

I've read about messing with BIOS settings but I'm unfamiliar with specifics, can anyone help? or just tell me if these RAM sticks are incompatible?

The RAM stick on the top SUPER-TALENT, is the 2 i have installed already totalling 4GB.

[image: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2tkp6sohxjrNVBQUHFPQ05qa3ZadjN1Wk5pa3pCSU5leFRR]

Motherboard: ASUS P5QE
-https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P5Q/

Comment: One problem I see with the A-TECH stick is that it's ECC RAM. Your specifications say that it needs to be non-ECC, un-buffered RAM. If you're adding both sticks, the ECC RAM is the one that is probably causing the problems.

Comment: great, yes.. that must be it. now to figure out how to ship something back through amazon. lol. thanks! i'll close this out once i can confirm.

Comment: Shipping it back to Amazon is a breeze. If it is the ECC RAM that is the issue, just @me and I can move it to an answer.

Comment: @DrZoo - cool thanks! is non-ECC way more expensive? looks like it's 255$ for the same kit i bought for $50 .. ?  on amazon: https://www.amazon.com/Pavilion-m9517c-NON-ECC-PC2-6400-Tech/dp/B00M4G43U6/ref=sr_1_3?srs=7584072011&ie=UTF8&qid=1481213567&sr=8-3&keywords=16gb+non-ecc+ddr2+6400]

Comment: Non-ECC is actually cheaper. ECC is more expensive because it has a type of error correction. The reason it's expensive is because it's DDR2 which is old and hard to find. So essentially it's overpriced because it's not manufactured as much. I'm having no problem finding 4 GB kits, but the 16 GB kits seem to be hard to find in non ECC.

Comment: @DrZoo - is this right: https://www.amazon.com/PC2-6400-DDR2-800MHz-Non-Ecc-240Pin-Desktop/dp/B01GLGSIWI    sorry and thank you.. just really need to get this machine ram'ed up for some development.

Comment: Unfortunately that RAM doesn't work either because it's only for an AMD motherboard, for whatever reason. How much RAM does the PC have currently?

Comment: Can you also just pop in the super talent stick of RAM and see if everything boots fine? If that's the case, can you just order another stick of the super talent brand?

Comment: the google drive link is invalid

Comment: i have two super-talent sticks 2gb each installed on it now (one of them was the top one in the pic)..

Comment: I'm trying to interpret this answer i found: http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1889183/ram-mobo-compatible.html#r12003860

Comment: OK -  i think this is it? http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA1K646A9856&cm_re=ddr3_1600-_-20-231-568-_-Product based on assumption that it handles 2 DDR3s

Comment: How many RAM slots does your board have? 4 or 6? Also, use @DrZoo when you respond so I get a notification.

Comment: @DrZoo - it has 4, but only 2 support DIMM3 from what i've read, though I can't find mention in specs.

Comment: The board that you have does not support any DDR3. The board that supports DDR3 has 6 RAM slots. 4 slots for DDR2 and 2 slots for DDR3.

Comment: @DrZoo - Who is your comment directed towards?

Comment: @DrZoo - can you please post an answer so I can mark it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ASUS P5Q motherboard does not support ECC RAM like you have in your picture, which is the reason why it is failing to boot.

The board that you have supports DDR2 1200/1066/800/667 MHz RAM. After doing some research, there are a some P5Q motherboards that support 16 GB of DDR2 RAM and 8 GB of DDR3 RAM. You can easily tell if your board supports the DDR3 option by looking how many RAM slots it has. If it has 4 slots, it only supports DDR2. If it has 6 slots, it supports the DDR2 option and the DDR3 option.

Comment: this is what I ended up ordering... http://www.memorystock.com/orderitem.asp?it=766ms-766 will update this posting if it works or not.. @ $80 a pop... crossing fingers.

Comment: @diegohb by the looks of it, that should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

ASUS P5Q Motherboard supports only DDR2 Non-ECC Memory.
Recommended speed is 800 MHz as max. Supports up to 1200 MHz.

ECC Registered is not supported and will not work with P5Q.

Refer this link for compatible RAM upgrades:

http://www.memorystock.com/memory/ASUSP5QMotherboardDDR2800MHz.html

Comment: so according to this there is not any compatible 4gb sticks for this motherboard.. ?

Comment: @diegohb - No; That list is memory that has been confirmed to be compatiable.  Any DDR2 800MHz non-ecc memory will work.